# Denwer и mkdir() функция

Tags: php, denwer

На локальном хостинге использую denwer, пытаюсь создать папку с помощью функции mkdir(),  ошибку не выдаёт но и ни чего не создаёт. Может в php.ini проблема? Подскажите что исправить.

```
if (!mkdir("../public/profile/dir/", 0777, true)) {
die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

Comment: Может быть из за того что вы находитесь в корневой директории и пытаетесь создать директоию за ее пределами ? Ну или создалась а вы не там смотрите? Проверьте директорию на уровень выше относительно к этому файлу с кодом

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую, в денвере использовать не относительные, а абсолютные пути, вариант универсален:

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public/profile/dir/", 0777, true);
```

Элемент $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] содержит путь к корневой директории сервера, если скрипт выполняется в виртуальном хосте, в данном элементе указывается путь к корневой директории виртуального хоста. Т.е. в конфигурационном файле httpd.conf виртуальный хост имеет директиву DocumentRoot, которой присвоено значение "D:/main", элемент $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] будет содержать значение "D:main". [Источник](http://php.su/articles/?cat=vars&page=015)